# SQL query to get customers who have purchased same product in two different quarters - Date Ranges

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

I have a table `Customer_Order_Data` with these columns:

1. customer_id
2. order_id
3. product_id
4. quantity
5. order_date

I want to find the customers who have purchased the same product (`product_id`) in two different quarters - Q1 2020(Jan-Mar) and Q2(Apr-Jun). For both the quarters the quantity purchase should be greater than 5.
I have an additional requirement to display the most frequently purchased quantity and most recently purchased quantity for the selected rows.

Let's say I have the following data -

| Order_id | Customer_id | product_id | Quantity | order_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | ABCD | B019 | 7 | 2020-01-01 |
| 00002 | ABCD | B019 | 6 | 2020-05-23 |
| 00003 | EFGH | B018 | 8 | 2020-01-12 |
| 00004 | ABCD | B019 | 7 | 2020-02-14 |
| 00005 | EFGH | B018 | 6 | 2020-04-18 |
| 00006 | ABCD | B019 | 7 | 2020-04-19 |
| 00007 | EFGH | B018 | 8 | 2020-03-12 |

I want to filter out the customers who have purchased same product in both Q1 and Q2 where `quantity  > 5`.
I want to group the rows based on customer_id.

Result expected -

| Customer_id | product_id | Most frequently Purachsed | Most Recently Purchased |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | B019 | 7 | 6 |
| EFGH | B018 | 8 | 6 |

Query I tried -

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where (
    select count(*) 
    from mytable t1 
    where 
        t1.customer_id = t.customer_id 
        and t1.product_id = t.product_id 
        and t1.quantity > 5
        and t1.order_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-03-31 23:59:59'
) > 1
and t.order_date BETWEEN '2020-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2020-06-30 23:59:59'
and t.quantity > 5;
```

This query is not correctly filtering out the customers who purchased same product in both the quarters.
Also, I am not understanding how to add the dummy columns for Most Frequently purchased quantity and Most Recently purchased quantity for a product

Comment: what is your mysql version

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph Sorry my bad - It's not MYSQL , It is using Redshift.

Comment: you said EFGH should not show up, however in the expected result you have shown it, can you recheck the expected results

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph - Corrected.

Comment: EFGH shouldnt come up in the expected results isnt it?. EFGH-B018 has quantity =1 in the second quarter and therefore according to the rules "For both the quarters the quantity purchase should be greater than 5"?.

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph - Corrected.

Comment: unless there is some caching going on with SO, i still see your expected results as follows Customer_id product_id Most frequently Purachsed Most Recently Purchased
ABCD B019 7 6
EFGH B018 8 6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226510/discussion-between-george-joseph-and-sapna-tiwari).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:
These are rather complicated constraints.  But it seems quite amenable to window functions and aggregation:

```
select customer_id, product_id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then quantity end) as most_recent_quantity,
       max(case when cpq_cnt = max_cpq_cnt then quantity end) as most_common_quantity
from (select t.*,
             max(cpq_cnt) over (partition by customer_id, product_id) as max_cpq_cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by customer_id, product_id order by order_date desc) as seqnum,
                   count(*) over (partition by customer_id, product_id, quantity) as cpq_cnt
            from mytable t
            where t.order_date >= '2020-01-01' and
                  t.order_date < '2020-07-01' and
                  t.quantity > 5
           ) t
     ) t
group by customer_id, product_id
having min(order_date) < '2020-04-01' and
       max(order_date) >= '2020-04-01';
```

The innermost subquery does the following:

- It filters the rows to the time range you care about.
- It enumerates the rows per customer/product by the `order_date` so you can determine the most recent quantity.
- It counts the number of times each quantity appears.

The middle subquery then calculates the maximum of the quantity.

Finally, the outer subquery does the following:

- It uses conditional aggregation to get the most recent quantity.
- It uses conditional aggregation to get the most frequent quantity.
- It filters the results to ensure that there is at most one order per quarter.